# Importing reference to Windows Media Player

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, windows-media-player

After several hours I once managed to import the Windows Media Player.

Now I need to do it again, and I'm desperate because I don't see which file I need to import.

The reference in my old project looks like that:
[image]

The files I get offered while trying to refence them looks like this:
[image]

Does anybody perhaps know right away how to import the Windows Media Player?

I thought this was a valid question for stackoverflow because I'm stumbling over this issue for the second time now.

Answer (score 0):

I got it: 
Right-Click the toolbox, add "Windows Media Player" (COM component tab) and drag it onto a form.